# How to properly inherit an FXML annotated attribute for having it available in a subclass?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, fxml

**Problem**

I'm trying to implement the transmission of messages over a Controller Area Network, where the messages are built from user's inputs through a GUI created with JavaFX.

I have a `MainController` class which is linked to a Main.fxml.  In the `MainController` I have defined an FXML annotated TextField attribute `in_desiredVelocity` which is correctly linked to its `fx:id` in Main.fxml.

Then I have defined an abstract class `canMessage` which defines the backbone of a message which has to be sent over the network.

Now the class `PcToVcuMessage` implements a particular type of canMessage. In order to be able to access the FXML attribute (defined in `MainController`) I've decided that the abstract class `canMessage` extends `MainController`, and `PcToVcuMessage` extends `canMessage`.

The application compiles correctly but when I enter, in the GUI, the TextField `in_desiredVelocity` a `NullPointerException` is launched.

**Question**

Despite the above FXML attribure is inherited by `PcToVcuMessage` (which inherits from the abstract class `canMessage` and this one extends the `MainController`), how can I use it in this class to achieve my goal?

**Main**:

```
package canbusgui;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class MainApplication extends Application {
    public static Stage stage = null;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        
        stage.setOnCloseRequest(event -> {
           System.exit(0);
        });

        MainApplication.stage = stage;

        // Create a FXMLLoader to load the FXML file that defines the user interface
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(MainApplication.class.getResource("MainView.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load());

        stage.setTitle("CANbus GUI");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setResizable(false);
        stage.setMinHeight(768);
        stage.setMinWidth(1366);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

**MainController**:

```
package canbusgui;

import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;


public class MainViewController {
  @FXML
  protected TextField in_desiredVelocity;

  @FXML
  public void initialize (){

        in_desiredVelocity.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, event -> {
                if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                    try {
                        sendMessage(new PcToVcuMessage("222"));
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                }
        });
  }
  

  public void sendMessage(canMessage message) throws Exception {
        
        message.constructData();
       
        message.validateInputs();
        
        byte[] data = message.getData();

        // Send the data array to the CAN bus
        canBusController.sendCommand(HexFormat.fromHexDigits(message.getId()), data);
  }

}
```

**canMessage.java** (it contains an abstract class `canMessage` and `PcToVcuMessage` extends it):

```
package canbusgui;

import static java.lang.Integer.parseInt;

public abstract class canMessage extends MainViewController{

    // Declare common attributes
    protected String id;
    protected byte[] data;

    public canMessage(String id) {
        this.id = id;
        // Initialize an empty byte array for data
        this.data = new byte[8];
    }


    // Define an abstract method to construct the data array
    public abstract void constructData();

    // Define an abstract method to validate the inputs
    public abstract void validateInputs() throws Exception;

    // Define a getter method for the data array
    public byte[] getData() {
        return this.data;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

}


// Define a subclass for PC_to_VCUMessage message
class PcToVcuMessage extends canMessage {


    public PcToVcuMessage(String id) {
        // Call the superclass constructor
        super(id);
    }


    // Override the constructData method
    @Override
    public void constructData() {


        data[0] = (byte) 0;
        data[1] = (byte) 0;
        data[2] = (byte) 0;
        data[3] = (byte) parseInt(in_desiredVelocity.getText()); //HERE in_desiredVelocity is null and a NillPointerException is launched
        data[4] = (byte) 0;
        data[5] = (byte) 0;
        data[6] = (byte) 0;
        data[7] = (byte) 0;
    }

    public  void validateInputs() throws Exception{}


}
```

**EDIT**

The format of the CAN message is the following: ID(hex), data0, data1, data2, data3, ......, data7. So, when I call the `PcuToVcuMessage`'s constructor in the controller I'm passing the ID of the message 222 (which, btw, is specified in the data sheet of the device)

In `PcuToVcuMessage` I need to acess to the FXML attribute `in_desiredVelocity` which has been set by the user by typing the value in the TextField of the GUI: in this way it is possible to retrieve the value typed by the user in order to build the message.

**EDIT2**

Since there can be multiple messages with different IDs, I have thought to use polymorphism in the sendMessage method in the controller. Furthermore there can be messages which needs to access more than one FXML attribute from controller class.

Comment: *"In order to be able to access the FXML attribute (defined in `MainController`) I've decided that the abstract class `canMessage` extends `MainController`"*. This simply isn't going to achieve what you want. Inheritance is a relationship between classes, not between objects. Inheritance is not going to let one object directly access the value of an instance variable in another object, even if the classes used to create those objects are related be inheritance.

Comment: Off-topic: please use proper Java naming conventions. It's difficult to read your code when classes are named like variables, and names of things have unexpected underscores, etc.

Comment: @James_D I think I should use _aggregation_  instead of inheritance, but I cannot see how to proceed

Comment: It really doesn't make a lot of sense for one controller to directly access a field in another controller (especially an `@FXML`-annotated field, which represents a UI element). Consider using a [MVC approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32342864/applying-mvc-with-javafx) to share *data* between controllers.

Comment: Though it looks like you are trying to implement a message bus to transmit the data anyway. I'm much less familiar with that design pattern, but since you're using it, there should be no need for the second controller to access the text field.

Comment: Why don't you just make a `private int desiredVelocity` field in `PcuToVcuMessage`, and initialize it in the constructor. Then just pass the value to the constructor when you call it in the controller. It's not really clear what you're trying to do here.

Comment: @James_D The format of the CAN message is the following: ID(hex), data0, data1, data2, data3, ......, data7.  So, when I call the  `PcuToVcuMessage` 's constructor in the controller I'm passing the ID of the message (which, btw, is specified in the data sheet of the device) 222.

Comment: @James_D In `PcuToVcuMessage` I need to acess to the FXML attribute `in_desiredVelocity` which has been set by the user by typing the value in the TextField  of the GUI: in this way I can retrieve the value typed by the user in order to build the message.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256663/discussion-between-giuseppe-and-james-d).

Comment: I can read your code. I was asking why you couldn't have a constructor that took the data (in some appropriate format) as well as the id. That would be the obvious way to approach this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simply isn't what inheritance does. Inheritance is a relationship between *classes*, not between *objects*.

When you do

```
public class MainViewController {
    // ...
    protected TextField inDesiredVelocity;
    // ...
}
```

it means that every instance of `MainViewController` will have a field called `inDesiredVelocity` of type `TextField`.

When you do

```
public abstract class CanMessage extends MainViewController {
    // ...
}
```

it means that every instance of `CanMessage` is also an instance of `MainViewController`.

When you load the FXML, the `FXMLLoader` creates an instance of `MainViewController` (because you have `fx:controller="canbusgui.MainViewController"` in the FXML) and initializes the `inDesiredVelocity` field *in that instance* with a reference to the text field declared in the FXML.

Later in your controller, you do

```
new PcToVcuMessage("222")
```

which, of course, creates a new instance of `PcToVcuMessage` with id `"222"`. Since `PcToVcuMessage` inherits from `CanMessage`, that new instance is also an instance of `CanMessage`, and since `CanMessage` inherits from `MainViewController`, that instance is also an instance of `MainViewController`, and since every instance of `MainViewController` has a field `inDesiredVelocity`, this new instance of `PcToVcuMessage` has a field called `inDesiredVelocity` of type `TextField`.

However, at no point do you initialize that field (and there's no sensible way to do so), so the `inDesiredVelocity` field in your `PcToVcuMessage` is null.

---

It doesn't make any sense to do any of this. I don't really understand what your domain model is (and I probably don't need to to answer this question), but it doesn't make any sense for a `TextField` to be part of an object whose type is some kind of message.

Instead, it probably makes sense for the data that is being sent by this message to be part of the `PcToVcuMessage`. I.e. you can do

```
class PcToVcuMessage extends CanMessage {

    private int desiredVelocity ;


    public PcToVcuMessage(String id, int desiredVelocity) {
        // Call the superclass constructor
        super(id);
        this.desiredVelocity = desiredVelocity;
    }


    // Override the constructData method
    @Override
    public void constructData() {


        data[0] = (byte) 0;
        data[1] = (byte) 0;
        data[2] = (byte) 0;
        data[3] = (byte) desiredVelocity;
        data[4] = (byte) 0;
        data[5] = (byte) 0;
        data[6] = (byte) 0;
        data[7] = (byte) 0;
    }

    public  void validateInputs() throws Exception{}


}
```

and in the controller replace `new PcToVcuMessage("222")` with

```
new PcToVcuMessage("222", Integer.parseInt(inDesiredVelocity.getText()))
```

Then just remove the `extends MainViewController` from the `CanMessage` class. This obviously makes no sense at all (a message is not a thing that controls a UI).

Some unrelated issues with your code:

1. Don't register key handlers with text fields. To handle the user pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>, use an action handler in the usual way.
2. Name classes and variables appropriately. Class names should be *nouns* (they represent *things*). `CanMessage` is a verb (or verbal phrase). Probably `Message` is more appropriate, but again I don't really understand what you are modeling here.